# detect collision between rectangle and circle while moving

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I am trying to make a simple recreation of pong for a friend and I am having trouble detecting when the ball hits the paddle so that I can have it bounce off. Below is my function for detecting collisions, if someone could help troubleshoot this so that when the ball hits the paddle the collision function returns true and the ball is redirected it would be much appreciated.

```
function checkWalls(){
// Bounce off right wall
if(ball.getX() + ball.getRadius() > getWidth()){
    dx = -dx;
}

// Bounce off left wall
if(ball.getX() - ball.getRadius() < 0){
    dx = -dx;
}

// Bounce off bottom wall
if(ball.getY() + ball.getRadius() > getHeight()){
    endGame();
}

// Bounce off top wall
if(ball.getY() - ball.getRadius() < 0){
    dy = -dy;
}

//detect collision betweeen ball and paddle, return true or false
function collision(ball,paddle){
var distX = Math.abs(ball.x - paddle.x-paddle.w/2);
var distY = Math.abs(ball.y - paddle.y-paddle.h/2);

if (distX > (paddle.w/2 + ball.r)) { return false; }
if (distY > (paddle.h/2 + ball.r)) { return false; }

if (distX <= (paddle.w/2)) { return true; } 
if (distY <= (paddle.h/2)) { return true; }

var dx=distX-paddle.w/2;
var dy=distY-paddle.h/2;
return (dx*dx+dy*dy<=(circle.r*circle.r));
}

//Bounce off paddle
if(collision == true){
    dy= -dy;
}
```

}

Comment: `if(collision == true)` you are not running the `collision` function, you are just testing against its reference

Comment: Without going into the maths or the point made by Patrick Evans: your code could potentially explode under the right circumstances. If the ball moves too quickly over time it might "phase" through the paddle by not colliding with it in an update step. It might also be an idea to update the ball to where it would have been if it collided in real life, instead of waiting until the next step to move it back up a bit.